# use angular material for lower version of angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

My application is made in angular 5, I want to implement angular material into it.
How can I do that? As there seems to be a compatibility issue between the latest version of material with angular 5. I am new to Angular, so Please bear with me as this may be a simple issue but I don't seem to get around it.

Comment: Use an older version of Material..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the v5 version of Angular Material instead of the latest (v6).

```
npm install --save @angular/material@5.2.5 @angular/cdk@5.2.5
```

Or update your package.json directly and then run `npm install`:

```
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
```